# How to add programmatically Tabs in TabLayout on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

In my application I want create **dynamically** `tabs` in `tabLayout` and I want when get data **from server** and this data **count > 0** then create `tab`.
For TabLayout I use this library : https://github.com/egemenmede/etiyabadgetab

**For this job I write below codes:**

```
        FullSearchSendData sendData = new FullSearchSendData();
    sendData.setKey(fullSearchText);
    sendData.setLoadImages(true);
    sendData.setSearchInCelebrities(true);
    sendData.setSearchInMovies(true);
    sendData.setSearchInSeries(true);
    sendData.setSearchInEpisodes(true);
    sendData.setSearchInUsers(true);
    sendData.setPageIndex(1);
    sendData.setPageSize(10);
    sendData.setMaxDistance(1);

    fullSearch_LoadLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<FullSearchResponse> call = api.getFullSearch(sendData);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<FullSearchResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FullSearchResponse> call, Response<FullSearchResponse> response) {
            FullSearchResponse searchResponse = response.body();
            if (searchResponse.getData().getCelebritiesCount() > 0) {
                celebritiesCount = searchResponse.getData().getCelebritiesCount();
                celebrityList.clear();
                celebrityList.addAll(searchResponse.getData().getCelebrities());
            }
            if (searchResponse.getData().getMoviesCount() > 0) {
                movieCount = searchResponse.getData().getMoviesCount();
                movieList.clear();
                movieList.addAll(searchResponse.getData().getMovies());
            }
            if (searchResponse.getData().getSeriesCount() > 0) {
                serieCount = searchResponse.getData().getSeriesCount();
                seriesList.clear();
                seriesList.addAll(searchResponse.getData().getSeries());
            }
            if (searchResponse.getData().getUsersCount() > 0) {
                usersCount = searchResponse.getData().getUsersCount();
                userList.clear();
                userList.addAll(searchResponse.getData().getUsers());
            }

            setupViewPager(fullSearch_ViewPager);
            setupTabs();

            fullSearch_LoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //fullSearch_Swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FullSearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            fullSearch_LoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fullSearch_ReloadLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

private void setupTabs() {
    if (celebritiesCount > 0) {
        fullSearch_tabLayout.addTab(new TabLayout(context).newTab());
        fullSearch_tabLayout.selectEtiyaBadgeTab(0)
                .tabTitle("Celebrities")
                .tabTitleColor(R.color.white)
                .tabBadge(true)
                .tabBadgeCount(celebritiesCount)
                .tabBadgeCountMore(false)
                .tabBadgeBgColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                .tabBadgeTextColor(R.color.white)
                .tabBadgeStroke(2, R.color.white)
                .tabBadgeCornerRadius(15)
                .createEtiyaBadgeTab();
    }
    if (movieCount > 0) {
        fullSearch_tabLayout.addTab(new TabLayout(context).newTab());
        fullSearch_tabLayout.selectEtiyaBadgeTab(1)
                .tabTitle("Movies")
                .tabTitleColor(R.color.white)
                .tabBadge(true)
                .tabBadgeCount(movieCount)
                .tabBadgeCountMore(false)
                .tabBadgeBgColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                .tabBadgeTextColor(R.color.white)
                .tabBadgeStroke(2, R.color.white)
                .tabBadgeCornerRadius(15)
                .createEtiyaBadgeTab();
    }
    if (serieCount > 0) {
        fullSearch_tabLayout.addTab(new TabLayout(context).newTab());
        fullSearch_tabLayout.selectEtiyaBadgeTab(2)
                .tabTitle("Series")
                .tabTitleColor(R.color.white)
                .tabBadge(true)
                .tabBadgeCount(serieCount)
                .tabBadgeCountMore(false)
                .tabBadgeBgColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                .tabBadgeTextColor(R.color.white)
                .tabBadgeStroke(2, R.color.white)
                .tabBadgeCornerRadius(15)
                .createEtiyaBadgeTab();
    }
    if (usersCount > 0) {
        fullSearch_tabLayout.addTab(new TabLayout(context).newTab());
        fullSearch_tabLayout.selectEtiyaBadgeTab(3)
                .tabTitle("Users")
                .tabTitleColor(R.color.white)
                .tabBadge(true)
                .tabBadgeCount(usersCount)
                .tabBadgeCountMore(false)
                .tabBadgeBgColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                .tabBadgeTextColor(R.color.white)
                .tabBadgeStroke(2, R.color.white)
                .tabBadgeCornerRadius(15)
                .createEtiyaBadgeTab();
    }
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    if (celebritiesCount > 0) {
        adapter.addFrag(FullSearchCelebritiesFragment.getInstance(celebrityList, celebritiesCount, fullSearchText), "Celebrities");
    }
    if (movieCount > 0) {
        adapter.addFrag(FullSearchMovieFragment.getInstance(movieList, movieCount, fullSearchText), "Movies");
    }
    if (serieCount > 0) {
        adapter.addFrag(FullSearchSeriesFragment.getInstance(seriesList, serieCount, fullSearchText), "Series");
    }
    if (usersCount > 0) {
        adapter.addFrag(FullSearchUsersFragment.getInstance(userList, usersCount, fullSearchText), "Users");
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

**But when run application show me this error :**

```
Process: com.test.example, PID: 3804
                                                                   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tab belongs to a different TabLayout.
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:476)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:464)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:443)
                                                                       at com.test.example.Activities.FullSearch.setupTabs(FullSearch.java:173)
                                                                       at com.test.example.Activities.FullSearch.access$900(FullSearch.java:44)
                                                                       at com.test.example.Activities.FullSearch$1.onResponse(FullSearch.java:156)
                                                                       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

When click on first link in error message, go to this code :

```
fullSearch_tabLayout.addTab(new TabLayout(context).newTab());
```

How can I fix this and create **dynamically** `tabs` in `tabLayout` ?

Please help me, i really need your helps. Thanks all <3

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Call the [newTab()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout#newTab()) function on your [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) instance. The `new` keyword is the problem because you are creating a new instance of [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) for each new tab and trying to add it to an existing instance.

```
fullSearch_tabLayout.addTab(fullSearch_tabLayout.newTab());
```

Comment: thanks not show me error, but create 2 tab from 1 tab! for example : create 2 tab of user . such as : movie - series - user - user ! should create one tab of user

Comment: how to fix it? ?

Comment: @Jongle I'm not sure, I don't see a reason for duplication. Try to debug the code, maybe you'll find when duplication happens ( https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html )

Comment: @Jongle, Maybe you initially have tabs, just remove them first by tab.removeAllTabs()